# Start Launcher Selection Programmatically / Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-launcher, kiosk-mode

I'm developing an industrial app that's running effectively in a KIOSK mode - that is users must not be able to exit it.

To achieve this I've simply made the app a launcher/home screen replacement.  This works very effectively and so far seems to be working as a method of preventing people getting out.

The only problem I have is that if I'm not careful we're going to end up with bricked devices where we can't get back to a normal launcher application.

What I'm looking for is a method of programmatically presenting the Android Launcher Selection Dialog.

Android seems to do this on it's own when you first launch a launcher, but I can't figure out a way of doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I'm looking for is a method of pro grammatically presenting the Android Launcher Selection Dialog.

`Intent.createChooser()` returns an `Intent` that will launch a chooser (which I think is what you mean by "Android Launcher Selection Dialog") for a given `Intent`. So, create an `Intent` for `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`, wrap that in `Intent.createChooser()`, and call `startActivity()` on the resulting `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I tried it, but when my launcher defined as default launcher (the user checked the - use as default checkbox) - starting such activity as you described just restarting again my home activity (I guess because it's already defined as default) instead of popping the "home screen chooser" dialog/activity..  so my user can stuck forever on my applicaiton in this scenario.  any suggestions?

Comment: @TalKanel: If this is on a relatively recent HTC device in the US, that's perhaps an outcome of some patent infringement suits filed by Apple. See http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/23/linkify-problem-patent-behavior.html and http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/24/linkify-problem-detection-mitigation.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: it's on samsung galaxy 2 tablet (P5110) with ICS stock rom.     are you saying that in such situation as I described - I can stack the user forever on my app??

Comment: @TalKanel: It's more that you need to know the component for some other home screen. Allowing the user to choose one via `createChooser()` is the simple solution. If that is not working, try creating your own "chooser" via `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` and launching something that way. This sample app show a list of `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activities, but it could easily be adjusted to show a list of `MAIN`/`HOME` activities: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks. I don't know how I didn't think about this solution before.  that's exactly what I needed :->

Comment: It does not work on modern Android version. If a launcher has been selected as default, startActivity(Intent.createChooser()) does not show "Launcher Selector" dialog

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this question right you don't want to get the user out of your app if he don't want it?

I would do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;  
}
```

Now button clicks will be ignored for the activity. Now you only have to make a menu point for the exit.

Comment: I tried solutions like that to start with.
It unfortunately doesn't work so well.  As soon as you have a progress dialog, bring the status bar down or launch something like the camera they can press the home key and the user is out.
Android by design is very much targeted at preventing you from locking the user out in that fashion.  

Hence my question was as above:  
How to present Launcher Selection Dialog from within app which is already set as the default launcher.  

Thanks

Comment: yes, you have to do this on every activity, i could solve the problem with the progress dialog, i make my own with a popup and xml elements.

Comment: You can't for example do it on the status bar though, or the camera app?
My solution seems simpler, and more fail safe.  I've also read that Google see the ability to block the home button as a bug that they intend to resolve so it's not future proof.

Comment: sorry u can't prevent the Home key with this code - you need a Home screen app (or I've heard rumours it can be done with a lock screen app)