# Programmatically set what launcher is active

Tags: java, android, launcher

I have read  around a bit on this and I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Basically, I want to create an app that switches between launchers at user defined events (for example shaking the screen or entering a code).

I have looked at [Start Launcher Selection Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188954/start-launcher-selection-programmatically-android) so I am fairly certain that it is possible to start the launcher selection tool, I just don't know if there is a way to change between launchers automatically without requiring the selection tool.

The idea is that, since I am practicing with custom launchers I often times leave one running on my phone to test its functionality. However, this can lead to unexpected issues I would like to quickly get out of by switching over to the default launcher (things like I need to quickly make a call and my "Make a Call" button isn't acting like I had planned).

Is there a better way to go about this if automatic launcher switches is an impossible/bad way to go?

Answer (score 1):

> I just don't know if there is a way to change between launchers automatically without requiring the selection tool

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Malware authors would *love* the ability to replace the user's home screen with one that did not offer a way to get back into the regular one.

The user has to be involved in the decision over what home screen implementation to use.

Comment: Blast security! This is the part about malware that makes me more angry than the harm it actually does on my computer. I hate having to jump through hoops for dishonest people... BUT I understand it 100%. I was just hoping there may be some way to do it.

Comment: @zgc7009: For your own personal use, there may be some way for an app running with superuser privileges on a rooted device to do it.